# Javascript 'onclick' not working in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, google-chrome

I am using datatables to dynamically create a table and populate it with data. So far so good. Then I try to use onclick() to make certain td elements clickable so they redirect me to another page.

The problem is: clicking on the td's does absolutely nothing in Chrome. It works fine in IE though.

Here's the html code.

```
<body id="dt_example">
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_numberOfRows" id="currency_numberOfRows" value="<%=currency_numberOfRows %>"></input>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_numberOfColumns" id="currency_numberOfColumns" value="<%=currency_numberOfColumns %>"></input>
<div id="demo">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="currency_example" tableType="currency_clickableTDs">
<thead><tr>
<th class="heading"></th>
<th class="heading"><%=header_data%></th>
<th>% of Total</th>
<th>Total</th>
</tr></thead>   
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<th class="heading">*Dynamically Added Heading*</th>

<td valign=middle class="underline">***Clickable Cell***</td>
<td valign=middle>*Dynamically Added Data*</td> 
<td valign=middle>*Dynamically Added Data*</td>
</tr>
</tbody>            
</table>
</div>
```

The javascript code is

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$(document).ready(function() {
var counter=(document.getElementById("currency_numberOfColumns").value)*2+1;
var tempaoColumns = [];
for(i=0;i<=counter;i++){
    if(i==0)
        {tempaoColumns[i] = null;}
    else
    {   tempaoColumns[i] = { "sType": "numeric-comma" };} 
    }

            $('table.display').dataTable({

                "aoColumns": tempaoColumns,
                "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip', 
                "aaSorting": [[ 1, "desc" ]]
                });

        } );
</script>
```

and

```
function setTDOnclickEvents(val){
 var pageFrom = val;
 var colHeaders = [];
 var rowHeaders = [];


 var numberOfColumns = document.getElementById("currency_numberOfColumns").value;
 var numberOfRows = document.getElementById("currency_numberOfRows").value; 
 var table=document.getElementById("currency_example");


 for (var h=0; h <= numberOfColumns*2; h++) {

     //find every TR in a "clickableTDs" type table
     colHeaders[h]= (table.rows[0].cells[h].innerHTML);
     //alert(h)
     //alert(table.rows[0].cells[h].innerHTML)
     }

 for (var h=0; h < numberOfRows/2; h++) {

     //find every TR in a "clickableTDs" type table
     if(h==0)
         rowHeaders[h]= (table.rows[h].cells[0].innerHTML);
     else if(h==1){ 
         rowHeaders[h]= (table.rows[numberOfRows/2].cells[0].innerHTML);}
```

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cells' of undefined** in the above line

```
     else
         rowHeaders[h]= (table.rows[h-1].cells[0].innerHTML);
     }
var allTRs = new Array();

//go through all elements
if(document.forms[0].tab.value=="Currency"){
for (var h=0; h < document.all.length; h++) {

//find every TR in a "clickableTDs" type table
if (document.all[h].tagName == "TR" &&
    document.all[h].parentElement.parentElement.tableType == "currency_clickableTDs") {
  allTRs.push(document.all[h]);
}
}
}
else if(document.forms[0].tab.value=="Service"){
  for (var h=0; h < document.all.length; h++) {

        //find every TR in a "clickableTDs" type table
        if (document.all[h].tagName == "TR" &&
            document.all[h].parentElement.parentElement.tableType == "service_clickableTDs") {
          allTRs.push(document.all[h]);
        }
     }
    }
else if(document.forms[0].tab.value=="Project"){
  for (var h=0; h < document.all.length; h++) {

        //find every TR in a "clickableTDs" type table
        if (document.all[h].tagName == "TR" &&
            document.all[h].parentElement.parentElement.tableType == "project_clickableTDs") {
          allTRs.push(document.all[h]);
        }
     }
    }
else if(document.forms[0].tab.value=="Location"){
  for (var h=0; h < document.all.length; h++) {

        //find every TR in a "clickableTDs" type table
        if (document.all[h].tagName == "TR" &&
            document.all[h].parentElement.parentElement.tableType == "location_clickableTDs") {
          allTRs.push(document.all[h]);
        }
     }
    }


for (var i=1; i < allTRs.length; i++) {
for (var j=1; j < allTRs[i].cells.length; j++) {
  allTRs[i].cells[j].colHeader = colHeaders[j];
  allTRs[i].cells[j].rowHeader = rowHeaders[i];
  allTRs[i].cells[j].onclick = function (){
    if(this.innerHTML == "0.00" || this.innerHTML == "0"){
    alert("No data to represent!!!");
    }else{
      if((pageFrom == "GrossRevenueLevel") && (this.colHeader != "% of Total")&&(this.colHeader != "TOTAL")){
         goMyController(this.colHeader,this.rowHeader);
      }
  }}
}    }    }
```

Could someone please help me? Thanks in advance and sorry for the painfully long code.

P.S. I didn't put the entire html code as it would be too lengthy

Comment: This is still quite lengthy. You'll probably have more luck if you post just the line that throws the error and the line that sets up the click handler.

Comment: Are you intentionally not using jQuery? It would make things a lot easier in your case ... //find every TR in a "clickableTDs" type table for instance ..

Comment: @EvanKnowles `else if(h==1){ 
         rowHeaders[h]= (table.rows[numberOfRows/2].cells[0].innerHTML);}` gives an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cells' of undefined. The click handler is set by `allTRs[i].cells[j].onclick = function ()`. This is at the bottom of the code

Comment: @trainoasis I'm not very good at jQuery (and apparently not at javascript either:P). I am working on making the code compatible with Chrome, I didn't write it though.

Comment: @Amber What if the number of rows is odd? You'll be indexing something like `table.rows[3.5].cells`, which definitely won't exist.

Comment: @EvanKnowles Doing this `else if(h==1){ 
    if(numberOfRows%2==0){rowHeaders[h]= (table.rows[numberOfRows/2].cells[0].innerHTML);}}` removed the error message but the td element still does nothing on being clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I replaced the javascript code with

```
function setTDOnclickEvents(val){
 var pageFrom = val;
 var bhal=$("#tab").val();

 if(bhal=="Currency"){
     var $tables = $("#currency_example tr");

 }
 else if(bhal=="Service"){
     var $tables = $("#service_example tr");

 }
 else if(bhal=="Project"){
     var $tables = $("#project_example tr");

 }
 else if(bhal=="Location"){
     var $tables = $("#location_example tr");

}

 $tables.each(function (i, el) {

        var $tds = $(this).find('td.underline');

     $tds.click(function(){
         var hetch = $(this).html();
         var hindex = $(this).index();
         var colHeada= $tds.closest('table').find('th').eq(hindex).html();
         var rowHeada= $tds.closest('tr').find('th').html();

         if(hetch == "0.00" || hetch == "0"){
                alert("No data available for this selection.");
                }else{
                  if((pageFrom == "GrossRevenueLevel") && (colHeada != "% of Total")&&(colHeada != "TOTAL")){
                     alert(colHeada);
                     alert(rowHeada);
                  }
              }
     }); 
 });
}
```

and it's working now.